# Flip matching substrings

Tags: javascript, regex, string

Is there a clean way to reverse in place substrings matching a particular regex in JavaScript?

For ex for a regex like `/[a-g]+/` and a string like `"sgsadebfdzgbd"` to get `"sgsdfbedadbg"` Where only the substrings `"adebfd"` and `"gbd"` were reversed in-place.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use custom function for `replace`:

```
your_string.replace(/([a-g]+)/g, function(all, word) {
     return word.split("").reverse().join("");
});
```

Example:

```
> "sgsadebfdzgbd".replace(/([a-g]+)/g, function(all, word) {
   return word.split("").reverse().join("");
});
"sgsdfbedazdbg"
```

You can also use this shorter, but (in my opinion) less clear version:

```
your_string.replace(/[a-g]+/g, function(word) {
     return word.split("").reverse().join("");
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Note that this is not possible by just using regular expressions:

The tricky bit is doing a string reversal for arbitrary long strings. A regular expression is equivalent in recognition power to a finite automaton. These (in a sense) have only a fixed finite sized storage. But to handle reversal of arbitrary long strings you need a storage which can store arbitrary entries, like a stack.

That is why you see the reverse function used in the other answer.